# Gnuplot displaying subscript despite noenhanced and escaping

Tags: gnuplot

First line of input file:

```
num\_threads find\_minimum\_edges label\_components merge\_components delete\_adj\_list delete\_graph other
```

Plot part of script:

```
plot for [i=2:(n_cols)] \
  input_file using 1:(sum [col=i:n_cols] column(col)) title columnheader(i) noenhanced with filledcurves x1
```

Somehow the above displays the line titles with a subscript instead of an underscore. I also tried not to escape the underscores but it didn't help either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a bug when using `noenhanced` together with `title columnheader`, using e.g. `title 'x_y' noenhanced` works fine.

You can use two backslashes to escape the underscore:

```
a_b c\\_d e_f
1 2 3
3 4 5
```

The script:

```
set termoption enhanced
plot for [i=2:3] 'data.txt' using 1:i title columnheader noenhanced, x title 'x_y' noenhanced
```

[image]

Comment: This is working i.e. I get the same result when running your script. It"s a minor matter, but what does the ... x title 'x_y' part do?

Comment: That should only demonstrate, that the `noenhanced` option works when you give the title as string, and that the error occurs only when using `title columnheader` :)